# How can i reuse th promise of ajax call in this case?

Tags: jquery

On body load I am using the AJAX call promise as shown below:

```
var stateIDselected = '';
$(document).ready(function() {
    var loadStates = $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: url + '/xxx/orn/getstates',
        jsonpCallback: 'jsonCallback',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        timeout: 7000,
        jsonp: false,
        cache: false,
        success: function(response) {},
        error: function(x, t, m) {}
      }); // End of loading states

      loadStates.done(function() {
          $.ajax({
              type: 'GET',
              url: url + '/xxx/orn/getdistricts?stateID=' + stateIDselected,
              jsonpCallback: 'jsonCallback',
              dataType: 'jsonp',
              timeout: 7000,
              jsonp: false,
              cache: false,
              success: function(response) {},
              error: function(x, t, m) {}
        });
    }); //  End of loading districts
}); // ready call ends here
```

If a State is selected I need to reform the districts select tag:

```
$(document).on('change', '#statesList', function(event) {
    var state_ID = $('#statesList').val().trim();
    stateIDselected = state_ID;

    // Here how can i use the ajax call present under loadStates.done()?
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can extract the logic current in the `done()` handler to it's own function which can be called from both locations in your code. Try this:

```
function getDistricts() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: url + '/xxx/orn/getdistricts?stateID=' + stateIDselected,
        jsonpCallback: 'jsonCallback',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        timeout: 7000,
        jsonp: false,
        cache: false
    });
}

loadStates.done(getDistricts); //  End of loading districts

$(document).on('change', '#statesList', function(event) {
    var state_ID = $('#statesList').val().trim();
    stateIDselected = state_ID;
    getDistricts();
});
```

You can also remove the `success` and `error` handlers if you're not using them.

Comment: Thank you let me try this one .